# How To load the array values as Dynamic?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, dynamic

[image: Sample]

As you See the Above picture is where i want to load the Counts from the array dynamically from the db.In this code iam using it as static how to show the count Dynamically  ?
This is the code i am currently using

````
       <h3 class="card-title fw-l"><?php echo  $dispcnt[0]->cnt;?> Counts</h3>```


I work in CodeIgniter
````

Comment: Refresh the page and they are dynamic. Seriously tough, if i understood correctly, you want to have the counters updating dynamically once rendered in the page correct? If that's the case, and excluding more complicated solutions, you need javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this solution:**

```
<?php
foreach($dispcnt as $object)
{
?>
    <h3 class="card-title fw-l"><?php echo  $object->cnt;?> Counts</h3>
<?php
}
?>
```